# Thunderbird does not provide the security option for account settings

Tags: security, email, thunderbird

On a fresh Xubuntu box I miss for some reason the menu item "Security" either "S/MIME" in the account settings in the usual place I've expected it.

[image: thunderbird-security-bug]

Same version of Thunderbird on an up-to-date machine does not show this behaviour.

Thus, I conclude that possibly there are some packages missing on the machine.

But which ones and how do I know?